# What was the name of this Werewolf band?

Tags: world-of-darkness, product-identification, werewolf-the-apocalypse

I remember that there was a Werewolf hard rock or metal band in some pre W20 sourcebook, but I am having trouble finding it again.

I know these pieces of the puzzle:

- There was certainly at least one Garou as part of the group.
- They were 'renowned' for their afterparties, which seemed to border on veil breaking.
- It *might* have been one of the city tribes (Glasswalkers or Bone Gnawers), though I am not really sure about that.

What was the band’s name and where was it mentioned?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I dug through the pile of "old stuff" in a comic shop, I encountered a battered up copy of "Moonstone Comics - Werewolf the Apocalypse: Fianna". Cover and what I noticed on a skim did match at least in big part what I remembered:

A rock band of werewolfs, calling themselves "Wolfshead", playing in the "Luna Loungue". Fianna. Just the part about the after party doesn't come up... so... close but not *quite* what I think it was.

This was most likely what [Zhacrie White](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/44589/zhacrie-white) meant when he commented

> Could it have been a graphic novel instead of a sourcebook? E.G [Werewolf the Apocalypse: Fianna](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10084359-werewolf-the-apocalypse)

Answer (score 2):

From W20 Kinfolk: A Breed Apart, pg 30, under Widdershins Society:

> Twenty years ago, Fianna Kinfolk Padraig and Aidan Conneely formed Widdershins, a Celtic folk band made up of their musically talented friends, all from Fianna stock. [...] Other Celtic folk groups have since joined the Widdershins Society: Wolves of the Highlands, specializing in Scottish folk songs and featuring bagpipes and Scottish pipe and drums, makes their way up
>   and down the Appalachian region; Gaelsong, an acapella group of Kinfolk, regularly tour the arts and crafts fairs and anywhere else that invites them; Taliesin’s Songbird, a Welsh folk band with connections on both sides of the Atlantic; and there are others. [...] While the Widdershins Society remains a Fianna society, other tribes have followed suit, and some have formed their own Kinfolk musical societies. Pan and the Muse, a duo made up of a pair of Black Fury fraternal twins, Andromache and
>   Andros Peloppaneus, bring ancient Greek songs into the modern age and anchor a group of Black Fury male and female Kinfolk; Gertie’s Jug Band centers around a large network of Bone Gnawer Kin, providing Cajun and Zydeco music as well as soup kitchens to feed and entertain homeless populations; Potlatch Songs consists of young Wendigo Kinfolk musicians eager to bring a strong environmental and natural living message to the world, believing that this
>   can help strengthen Gaia for the coming battle. Each tribe has at least one musical Kinfolk group providing musical and social connections.

That's all I got about Garou/Kinfolk bands. Does this help?

Comment: I hope it does! A Celtic folk band—much less an acapella or Zydeco band—is rarely also a "hard rock or metal band" as the question requests, but if it is, such a band is likely at least worth a (fictional) listen!

Comment: It's a good find, yet it does not match but two things that I am sure of: Pre W20 and reputated for having parties bordering a veil breech.

Answer (score 0):

The Widdershins are a Fianna Celtic folk band, is that what you’re thinking of?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. This answer looks like it has some potential, but it would be better if you included a reference to the source book (ideally with page numbers) that mentions the Widdershins. You can update your answer by clicking the [edit] button at the bottom of it.